# Merging the graphs in JMeter

Tags: graph, jmeter, execution, response-time

I ran a test in non-GUI mode of JMeter in different times.

Suppose that I ran it three times in non-GUI mode. So I want to have all three graphs in one graph. Is it possible to merge all graphs which are done in either GUI or non-GUI mode?

If this is possible, please let me know how with respect to the mode of execution...

Answer (score 0):

You can merge results and display in graph using  [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin

> Merge Results is a tool to merge files of results

Example of merging 2 files:
[image]
Result:
[image]

Comment: hi. thanku for this and I ll look into this and if I need specific calls comparision how do I do that

Comment: and why we need that offset can u explain in detail

Comment: @biyyapu you don't need the offset, you need to add rows with different results

Comment: It was not able to merge my files it saying error loading file check logs...what type of execution u added for merging may I know

Comment: u added a result which having same time stamp or what .. I need to merge different runs in diff timings

Comment: @biyyapu your question was general, for specific question can you ask a new question with more details?

Comment: hi... is there any possibility to make to diff graphs in one to compare like previous execution and current execution not to merge actually this time I need to show to graphs in one graph to find the difference in response times.. ant chances are there in jmeter..pls let me know

Comment: that merge result plugin wont works in my case it saying error  loading log every time